# projection graph in r

Tags: r, projection

How can I create a projection graph as appears on this page: http://www.businessinsider.in/Heres-A-Terrifying-Chart-Of-Projected-Ebola-Cases/articleshow/43259377.cms

My data:

```
> ddf
  time value
1    1    10
2    2    18
3    3    30
4    4    38
5    5    45
6    6    61
7    7    78
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(time = 1:7, value = c(10L, 18L, 30L, 38L, 45L, 
61L, 78L)), .Names = c("time", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I want to project it to time 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ggplot2's `stat_smooth` function with a forecasting method of your choise.
Use `fullrange=TRUE` to predict it for the whole range.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=time,y=value), data=ddf) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=TRUE, lty="dotdash") + xlim(1,20) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

If you also want the vertical line: Add `+ geom_vline(xintercept=7)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I make it log projection as used in given link? There seems to be no such method in stat_smooth()?

Comment: `stat_smooth` calls the function given by `method` with the default `formula = y ~ x`. If you want any other forecasting method or formula just modify method, y and x accordingly.

IMHO: Forecasting your timeseries until `time = 20` wont be very accurate as there is not enough data to base an projection on.